# Ruby- How to remove all words which have a specific pattern in a string

Tags: ruby

For example, the string is "I am very happy today". I want to remove all words containing the letter "a". So the output should be "I very". how can I do that?

Comment: You should say whether you want to keep extra spaces between words that are to be kept. Suppose, for example, `str = "I_am_very____grouchy_today"`, where spaces are represented by underscores (SO strips out extra spaces in comments). Do you want to return "I_very_grouchy" or "I_very____grouchy"

Comment: You've seen my question, but chose not to answer. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Similar to @Sam's answer, only smaller :) Uses the little known [Enumerable#grep_v](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep_v).

> Inverted version of #grep. Returns an array of every element in enum for which not Pattern === element.

```
"I am very happy today".split.grep_v(/a/).join(' ') # => "I very"
```

Comment: I foresee that @mudasobwa appears and posts a clever regex solution with negative lookaheads, or something. :)

Comment: U are so nice!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Help me a lot!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try splitting each word and removing the ones that have the letter 'a' and join the words together like this:

```
"I am very happy today".split.reject{ |word| word.include?("a") }.join(" ")
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with a regex :

- word boundary
- alphanumeric characters
- a
- alphanumeric characters
- word boundary

You need to remove the unneeded spaces then.

```
"I am very happy today".gsub(/\b\w*a\w*\b/i, '').strip.gsub(/\s+/, ' ')
```

The answers with `split` and `join` are cleaner, though.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply ^_^